# Comparing empirical distributions with an interaction effect

Tags: statistical-significance, interaction, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

My experiment includes two subject groups: *group1* and *group2*. Both groups undergo a behavioral test, the result of which is called “movement celerity” (this is my dependent variable). Both groups are tested under two conditions: *treatment off* (without treatment) and *treatment on* (with a drug being delivered).

I want to compare the treatment's effect across the two groups: is the treatment's effect different in group1 and in group2 (i.e. is the interaction term **group*treatment** significant)? My goal is to test the significance of this interaction term in relation to the “movement celerity” **empirical distribution functions**.

In other words: is the difference between the two empirical distributions for group1 (left subplot) different than the difference between the two empirical distributions for group2 (right subplot)?

[image]

How would you achieve such a goal?

Thank you